# Does having lots of threads WaitingForSingleObject() will worsen performance?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, winapi, synchronization

I have a code in C using WIN32 API.

in my program, the main Thread creates a lot of events (Using CreateEvent), and then creates a Thread (Using CreateThread) for each Event that WaitForSingleObject for it.

Does creating lots of Threads that WaitForSingleObject will worsen the main Thread performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "lots of threads"? Tens, hundreds, thousands?

Comment: Threads that block aren't scheduled, so their impact on another thread is zero. One thread per event is a bad idea, regardless.

Comment: the problem is that I need to know what event signaled. I thought this would be a better solution than waitingForMultiple and checking manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is very little performance cost while a thread is waiting at a WaitForSingleObject call.  The thread will not be scheduled at all until the object it's waiting for is signaled.  It's very normal to design a program with several threads that wait, do some work, and wait again.

The costs to watch out for are:

- Constantly creating new threads instead of re-using threads.
- Locks with high contention.  As much as possible, let separate threads work with their own copies of data so that they don't need additional synchronization.  (Look up lock convoys.)
- I/O contention.  If your limiting factor is the speed you can move data in and out of memory (e.g., from disk or the network), then you're probably better off with fewer threads.
- Having many threads working at the same time.  You can have many of them waiting, but if the number of threads actually running at a given moment is much greater than the number of cores, then you'll start to lose the benefits of threading.
- Dividing the work into tiny slivers.  If your threads are waking up to do just a tiny amount of work, then the overhead of starting up and shutting down could become significant.  (This is analogous to a loop where the overhead of testing the loop condition is on the same order as the amount of work done in the body of the loop.)  "Tiny" is subjective and possibly machine-dependent.  You'll have to profile in order to tune the amount of work (assuming that it's adjustable).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have given good answers. However, if creating lots of threads is a concern, perhaps using [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be an alternative.

The "true" answer to your question really depends on what "lots" is, and what each thread is supposed to do when it's "triggered". Without understanding that, it's almost impossible to say what is the best solution. Hence I'm suggesting an alternative.

Whenever performance is part of a problem, measure, change, measure, change, measure is the way to go. Don't just follow some advice on the internet thinking "This page says this is the right solution, so I'm doing that". The devil is often in the details, so what someone finds is right in their case may not be right in your case, because the exact workload inside the threads is different, for example. To make it more complicated, computer architecture changes continually, so what is the "right" solution today isn't necessarily the right solution in five years, or wasn't the right solution five years ago.